# Iterating through an array in javascript unexpected result

Tags: php, javascript

I thought that I was approaching this correctly but it appears not.

I have the following function:

```
function oMain(){
    var allMyData = <? echo htmlspecialchars($jsData, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'utf-8')?>;
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'x');
    data.addColumn('number', 'mid');
    var i=0;
    alert(allMyData.length);
    for(i=0;i<allMyData.length;i++){

    }

    alert(allMyData[i+1,0] + "," + allMyData[i+1,1]);
}
```

where `allMyData` looks like this:
`[["20121031095013","1.315"],["20121031095029","1.315"],["20121031095046","1.315"],["20121031095102","1.315"],["20121031095118","1.315"],["20121031095134","1.315"],....`

which to me seems okay.

Now:
My Alert shows me something like this:
`20121031095013,1.315,20121031095029,1.315`

where I am anticipating:
20121031095029,1.315

Could someone please help me see the error i am making?

Thank you

Comment: Please don't echo code directly into JavaScript like this.  You're introducing a potential XSS security hole.  Also, `htmlspecialchars()` encodes your data for the _HTML context_, not the JavaScript context.

Comment: is it possible you want the laert inside the for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`allMyData[i+1,0]` returns the first array inside that other huge array. I think you meant this:

`alert(allMyData[i+1][0] + "," + allMyData[i+1][1]);`

That way, you are selecting the array `i+1`, and the the separate values inside of that.

If you want a separate alert for every array inside your array, you need to place the alert statement inside the for loop:

```
function oMain(){
    var allMyData = <? echo htmlspecialchars($jsData, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'utf-8')?>;
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'x');
    data.addColumn('number', 'mid');
    var i=0;
    alert(allMyData.length);
    for(i=0;i<allMyData.length;i++){
        alert(allMyData[i+1][0] + "," + allMyData[i+1][1]);
    }
}​​​​
```